# Zend Framework: Show table status query

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

How I can write this query in zend:

```
$tableStatus = mysql_query("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'table_Name'");
```

Because I need to get next auto increment number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about?

```
$stmt = $dbAdapter->query("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'table_name';");
$tableStatus = $stmt->fetchObject();
```